Can we classify the structure of an infinite soluble $p$-group of bounded exponent?
By Baer-Pruffer Theorem, we know that, if $A$
is an abelian $p$-group of bounded exponent, then $A$
is a direct sum of cyclic $p$-groups.
Now, assume that  $A$
is an infinite soluble  $p$-group of bounded exponent.  Can we classify the structure of such a group?
For example, by Baer-Pruffer Theorem, we can classify the structure of $A/A'$ as direct sum of cyclic $p$-groups.

If a torsion group is solvable, then it is locally finite. The requirement of local finiteness is superfluous.

What does "classify" mean in this context? We can't classify groups of order $2^{11}$.
